# How do I consolidate my code to have one variable that changes for each input?

Tags: python

I'm building a program that will take the skillsets of different candidates for a given job, and check to see if they have the required skills. I have figured out how to make this work, but I don't know how to do it without writing "candidate1", "candidate2" etc. Is there a more efficient way to do this?:

```
list_of_qualities = ['Experience in Cold Calling', 'Experience in Door to 
Door Sales', 'Experience in Account Management','Experience in Warm Leads','Experience in Presenting', 'Experience in Negotiation',\'Experience in Leadership', 'Experience in Closing']

cold_calling = list_of_qualities[0]
door_to_door = list_of_qualities[1]
account_management = list_of_qualities[2]
warm_leads = list_of_qualities[3]
presenting = list_of_qualities[4]
negotiation = list_of_qualities[5]
leadership = list_of_qualities[6]
closing = list_of_qualities[7]

required_qualities = [cold_calling, presenting, account_management, leadership, closing]
candidate1 = [cold_calling, presenting, account_management, leadership, closing, door_to_door]
candidate2 = [cold_calling, warm_leads, account_management, leadership]
candidate3 = [cold_calling, account_management]
matched_qualities1 = []
matched_qualities2 = []
matched_qualities3 = []
lacking_qualities1 = []
lacking_qualities2 = []
lacking_qualities3 = []

print("To view and apply for your job, candidates must have the following skillset:")
print(required_qualities)
print(" ")
print("The candidates have the following matching skills:")
```

#### Candidate 1

```
for i in candidate1:
    if i in required_qualities:
        matched_qualities1.append(i)
print("Candidate 1:", matched_qualities1)

for i in required_qualities:
    if i not in candidate1:
        lacking_qualities1.append(i)
```

#### Check if candidate 1 has all skills or not

```
if len(lacking_qualities1) == 0:
    print("             This candidate has all of the required skills")
else:
    print("    lacking:", lacking_qualities1)
```

Comment: keep skills in file a line for each candidate and read from file looping every line

Comment: There are lot of things that you can imporve in your code. For example you can use list comprehension instead of writing `for loop and if condition`. Check this http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. You can have a list of lists, or a dataframe. An array is also an option, but not really appropriate. Some other things to simplify your code:

You can do `cold_calling,door_to_door,account_management,warm_leads,presenting,negotiation,
leadership,closing = list_of_qualities`

Also, you can replace your for-loop with `lacking_qualities1=[quality in required_qualities if not quality in candidate1]`

If you create a list of candidates, you can do

```
lacking_qualities_list_of_list=[
       [quality in required_qualities if not quality in candidate]
       for candidate in list_of_candidates]
```